# C++ data structures wrong output (linked lists)

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

typedef struct node{
    int size;
    char* name;
    node* next;
}node;

void insertnodes( node** arrayhead , int index , node* ptr){

    index = index - 1 ;
    while ( index--){

        *arrayhead = (*arrayhead)->next;
    }
    (*arrayhead)->next = new node; 
    (*arrayhead)->next = ptr;   
}


int main(){
    int n = 4;
    node *A[n] ;

    for ( int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++){
        A[i] = NULL ;
    }

    A[0] = new node; 

    A[0]->size = 10;
    A[0]->name = new char;
    A[0]->name = "gunna";
    A[0]->next = NULL;
    //cout << A[0]->name << endl;


    node* ptr = new node ;
    ptr->size = 10;
    ptr->name = new char;
    ptr->name = "param";
    ptr->next = NULL;


    insertnodes(&A[0] , 1 , ptr);

    node* ptrr = new node ;
    ptrr->size = 10;
    ptrr->name = new char;
    ptrr->name = "sidd";
    ptrr->next = NULL;
    insertnodes(&A[0] , 2 , ptrr);

    cout << A[0]->name << endl;
    cout << A[0]->next->name;



}
```

It should have to print  "gunna" and "param" .

but it is giving "param" and "sidd" as output.

I don'nt know where i am going wrong . I have tried a lot of things but i am still confused 
Pls help ... 
I am using code blocks to compile this program ..

Comment: Are you sure your code compiles? You are trying to initialize A (the array in main()) with a non-constant value.

Comment: @bku_drytt https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html - not really valid C++, but valid C99 and GCC accepts it in C++. Clang accepts it for POD types in C++.

Comment: Using an array for a linked list defeats the purpose.

Comment: @mastov I see, thanks for that link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `insertnodes()` you are passing a **double pointer** `node** arrayhead`, thus, by dereferncing it later, you are overwriting the current value of `next` pointer, which will later cause memory leak in your program.

What you should do instead is create a temporary variable `node* tmp` which you will change when the `index` decreases. Then, you don't need to allocate a new node to the next pointer, because **you already have a pointer you want to attach as `next`**.

The fixed code would look like this:

```
void insertnodes(node** arrayhead, int index, node* ptr) {
    index = index - 1;
    node* tmp = *arrayhead;
    while (index--) {
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }
    tmp->next = ptr;
}
```

**EDIT:** This is completely useless:

```
int n = 4;
node *A[n] ;

for ( int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++){
    A[i] = NULL ;
}
```

All you need to create a linked list is a single node (e.g. list's head).

---

But as this is a linked list, you don't need to pass index really. All you need is a `head`, over which you could iterate until you find `node->next` which will be `NULL` - this is the place you need to insert your new node at (this is how it's typically done).

Comment: I don't think you even need the to pass `index` to insert nodes at the end of the list. All you need to do is `while (tmp->next!=NULL)`. You are right about the point about memory leaks.

Comment: Exactly, you don't have to pass `index`, I wanted to point errors in the current version of code though.

Comment: well it ran... but i do have to allocate new node to the next pointer to make it run... And i am not getting this memory leak thing ..

can you explain...

And i am doing array of linked lists here so i have to to make that array....

Comment: Yes, you have to allocate new node but in your example you are doing it twice. The memory leak can be caused if you attach a `next` pointer for a given node for the second time. You won't be able to deallocate the node then, which will cause the memory leak. You really don't need an array - when you'll analyze your code you'll see you use only its item at index 0 (`A[0]`).

Comment: Ok .. I got the new node problem in my code... But can you pls help me with this memory leak thing , and is there  any site where i can read about it in deapth ...

Comment: Valgrind is one the best tools available out there, refer to this tutorial: http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/QuickStart.html and start with some simple examples of memory leaks: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-toughgame/